# OnsenUI + React - Unexpected output in Chrome

Tags: meteor, reactjs, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

This is my first time using OnsenUI with React. I really tried to copy the monaca helloworld example component parts, such as the page and toolbar and I'm expecting to see an output like an iOS screen on chrome, but instead I got this.

[image]

I'm using Mantra, and any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code?  It looks like you do not have everything imported.

Comment: Try this and see if this works:  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI-dist/2.0.0-rc.15/css/onsenui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI-dist/2.0.0-rc.15/css/onsen-css-components.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI-dist/2.0.0-rc.15/js/onsenui.js"></script>
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>`